# ¿Como evitar que mysql siempre se conecte a localhost?

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

Estoy tratando de hacer un servicio de correo y estoy usando dovecot pero al momento de querer ingresar como un usuario dovecot siempre me arroja el mismo error posftfix@localhost no existe lo cual es verdad porque no esta utilizando mi dominio .

Trate de entrar a la base de datos con lo siguiente :

```
$ mysql -u postfix@'dominio.com' -p
```

pero  despues de ingresar mi password me dice que el usuario no existe pero porque mysql concateno localhost con mi dominio de esta manera

```
postfix@'dominio.com'@'localhost'
```

Como puedo evitar que se trate de acceder por default a localhost en mysql

Comment: puedes colocar claves distintas así cuando se conecte estaras muuuy seguro, y te lo recomiendo puedes cometer un error epico!!!

Answer (score 0):

Si el servidor **no es el local** debes utilizar `-h`.

```
mysql> –h "nombre o ip del servidor" –u "nombre de usuario" –p "contraseña"
```

Si el servidor **es local**, se puede omitir `-h`:

```
mysql>  –u "nombre de usuario" –p "contraseña"
```

Se a de tener en cuenta que mysql por defecto no permite conexiones externas, se ha de habilitar explicitamente.